# Name of Distribution Related to the Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I am trying to find out if there's a standard name for the following distribution related to the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  This distribution is basically the same as the binomial distribution, but as if the second half of the probability mass function (PMF) is flipped and added to the first half.

I am assuming the binomial distribution's PMF is given by:

$$f(k) = \left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} \right) p^k q^{n-k}$$

where $q=1-p$, and $k \in \{0, 1, ..., n\}$.

The PMF of the distribution I am looking for the name of is then given by:

$$g(k) = f(k) + f(n-k)$$

when $n$ is odd, $k \in \{0, 1, ..., (n-1)/2\}$

and for $n$ even:

$$g(k) = \begin{cases} 
      f(k) + f(n-k) & k<n/2 \\
      f(n/2) & k=n/2 
   \end{cases}$$

where $k \in \{0, 1, ..., n/2\}$.

Comment: I doubt that there's a specific name for it.  I'd just call it the distribution of $n/2 - |n/2 - X|$ where $X$ has your binomial distribution.